# Qual è il senso di "basilisco" usato per chiamare una persona?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Il sarto della stradalunga*, di Giuseppe Bonaviri, ho letto:

> La strada era lunga e io avevo voglia di piangere e ritornare a casa, ma le lavandaie camminando dritte coi fardelli sulle teste polverose, mi gridavano: «Spicciati, **basilisca**! Non dormire, altrimenti faremo tardi».

Potreste spiegarmi cosa significa "basilisca" in questo brano? Nessuna delle accezioni di "basilisco" che ho trovato nei dizionari fa riferimento a un modo di chiamare una persona, eccetto quella di "[abitante, nativo della Basilicata](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/basilisco1)", ma in questo caso si tratta di una ragazza siciliana.

Comment: Ho trovato che [il basilisco nelle Madonie](https://www.lacucinaitaliana.it/storie/piatti-tipici/lultimo-produttore-di-ricotta-di-basilisco/) (monti della Sicilia) è una pianta. Suppongo che il significato voglia essere quello di muoversi e non stare fermo come una pianta. Ma è, ripeto, una mia supposizione.

Comment: Il basilisco mitologico aveva un sguardo letale: forse qui è ironico, come a dire a una persona mezza addormentata che ha occhi sfolgoranti. Per curiosità, fra i ragazzi di via Panisperna, Fermi era detto il “Papa”, Franco Rasetti il “Cardinale” ed Emilio Segrè appunto il “Basilisco”, per il suo carattere pungente e ironico.